# Does not contain a definition for "table" and no extension method "table" accepting

Tags: c#, migradoc

I'm trying to send data to PDF using MigraDoc. But I encountered this syntax error and could find the assembly reference to fix it.
Reason of the error is below:

```
        this.table = section.AddTable();
        this.table.Style = "Table";
        this.table.Borders.Color = TableBorder;
        this.table.Borders.Width = 0.25;
        this.table.Borders.Left.Width = 0.5;
        this.table.Borders.Right.Width = 0.5;
        this.table.Rows.LeftIndent = 0;
```

'table' is the problem here.
I'm stuck here any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You haven't declared an instance field named `table`
2. Or, perhaps you declared a local variable instead, in which case just remove `this.`.
3. Or, if you haven't declared either, change `this.table = section.AddTable()` to `var table = section.AddTable();` and remove `this.` from the other statements.

Comment: `var table = section.AddTable();`  fixed it thank you @dcastro